# How to concatenate strings in the function m_stream in C++?

Tags: c++, logging, concatenation

I'm writing a logger for my program in C++.

I have this piece of code:

```
void Log::Write(char* logline)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    m_stream << asctime (timeinfo) << logline << endl;
}
```

This is a log

Tue Oct 11 13:07:28 2011

I want a different output on a single line like this:
Tue Oct 11 13:07:28 2011 - This is a log

How can I do it?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't make sense of this.  What is the value of `logline`?  It doesn't look like your output agrees with your code.

Comment: Dont worry is just the write function, logline is the input.

Comment: Are you talking about reversing the order of the log and the time stamp?

Comment: Sorry. I've just edited the post.
I want to see this: Tue Oct 11 13:07:28 2011 - This is a log
and NO on 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is asctime():

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/asctime/

```
The string is followed by a new-line character ('\n') and the terminating null-character.
```

As the returned string is a C string, you could replace the \n with a \0:

```
char * str = asctime(timeinfo);
str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
```

AS long as you don't call ctime or asctime again, the content won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

As it said in [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kys1801b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The string result produced by asctime contains exactly 26 characters and has the form Wed Jan 02 02:03:55 1980\n\0

So if you don't want to write line ending symbol you could use use 'write' function specifying exact amount of characters to write like this

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;
time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
m_stream.write( asctime (timeinfo), 24 );
m_stream << " - " << logline << std::endl;
```

Of course in that case you should write comment explaining why '24' is used...

Comment: I find the solution that replaces the last \n with \0 more elegant and doesn't need a comment to explain what you are doing.